# AWS ubuntu instance Connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, aws

I've successfully setup an ubuntu instance.

I ssh'ed into it and installed the LAMP stack and Composer.

The next evening when I tried to connect I received a *connection refused* message.
The following is the verbose output:

```
ssh -vvv -i ~/Documents/AWS/.ssh/ubuntu-webserver-keys.pem ubuntu@13.10.8.21
OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "13.10.8.21" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 13.10.8.21 [13.10.8.21] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 13.10.8.21 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 13.10.8.21 port 22: Connection refuse
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Are you sure your IP hasn't changed? Do you have console access? Can you check if `sshd` is running? `sudo service sshd status`

Comment: To add to @Zachary Brady's comment.  Unless you have procured an Elastic IP and attached it to the instance, then you might have received a new IP address at any time.  Yes, it is confusing that a public, static IP is referred to as an[Elastic IP on AWS 
See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html] on AWS.